# Системный путь к папке PHP

Tags: php, windows, openserver, настройки, php.ini

Я использую openserver. Где находится папка php (указанная на [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5))?

Comment: а зачем вам знать путь папке? для подключения дебага? а он там не включён по умолчанию? так то надо искать где-то в modules.... а вообще в OS есть в контекстном меню есть пункты по редатированию php.ini

Answer (score 0):

OpenServer\modules\php\PHP_5-7\ext

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]